# Unity c# Photon - Set Parent of PhotonNetwork.Instantiate object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

What I'm trying to do is set the parent of new tool and make it visible on the server like 'PhotonNetwork.Instantiate'

```
var drop = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate("Tools/Weapons/" + Tool.name, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            
drop.transform.SetParent(collider.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(0));
```

Using **drop.transform.SetParent** it's only visible for the local player.

If you have any questions, ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code
drop.transform.SetParent(collider.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(0));
will not be excuted in any other clients or server. So I will create a script attached to the object to set parent when the object is created;

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SetParent : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject Tool;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Awake()
{
    gameObject.transform.parent = FindParent();
}

private Transform FindParent()
{
    Transform parent;
    //Find object should be parent
    return parent;
}
}
```

Comment: Not working :( There's a problem with  return parent; .

Comment: of course, you must find the parent yourself, for example through tag or layer or class attached to the parent object

Answer (score 2):

The right way Photon want you to do it is by using the "**Custom Instantiation Data"**
https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/instantiation

For example...

```
//1) The script where we you instantiate the object will pass the relevant data (The parent View ID):
  int parentViewID = PhotonView.Find(this.gameObject.getComponent<PhotonView>().ViewID);
  string word = "example";
  object[] myCustomInitData = new object[3];
  myCustomInitData[0] = parentViewID;
  myCustomInitData[1] = word; 
  
  PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("Players", "Player" transform.position, Quaternion.identity, 0, myCustomInitData);
    
//_______________________________________________________________________    

//2) The script that attached to our new Instantiate object:
//Make sure the prefab has PhotonView component on it !
  
  using Photon.Pun;

  public class RandomCall : MonoBehaviourPun, IPunInstantiateMagicCallback
  {
    GameObject parent;
    public void OnPhotonInstantiate(PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        object[] instantiationData = info.photonView.InstantiationData;
        parent = PhotonView.Find((int)this.customInstantiateData[0]).gameObject;
        string word = (string)instantiationData[1];
        this.transform.setParent(parentObject)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example: Set tag for parent object "Parent". Then you can find the object through this code: parent = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Parent").transform;